# Mislabeled problem with hospital data

Tags: machine-learning, python, data-cleaning, preprocessing, labelling

I am writing this post to ask or see if someone can help me with this problem in case you may have faced a similar situation.
My problem has to do with a ML tool that I am trying to develop in a context of information about the stays of a Hospital (I do not want to give a very deep description for privacy reasons but I will try to explain enough to understand the problem).

The problem to be solved can be summarized in that we want to be able to suggest which patients are the most potential to be chosen as "class 1" (let's call it that way) within all the stays that we have in the Hospital. To do this we have cases in which they are effectively class 1 (not a high number, there is also a problem of imbalance) and class 0, The big problem is that within this class there are cases that are effectively class 0 but there are also cases that should be class 1 but were not because sometimes simply because of issues of doctors or nurses this patient is not suggested to be class 1 (let's understand these cases as they did not realize or because of the stress of all the work they have or other issues did not think it could have been a good case of class 1 although for medical issues it was).

My managers to explain me this tool to develop give me clear examples in which they are indeed labeled as class 0 but should be class 1, the problem is that the casuistry in a hospital context is huge so this division is really complicated. I am trying based on the information I have, clinical information of the patient or the different categorizations that define each stay in the hospital, to make a method of clustering or classification, but I have a big problem because the ways in which each stay is classified, such as diagnosis, type of admission, reason for admission, etc, are categorical features with many classes.

And the problem gets even more complicated, but at least a little bit with this description, could you suggest me a good one for a case like this? or if you have faced a similar situation of mislabeled class, how could you correct the errors in the labels?

Thank you very much in advance and all the best!

Comment: I'd suggest you get clean, correct labels for some data that you're highly confident in and then train a model using these; predict on remaining data. For data with high confidence of being incorrect, get it validated and correct them, iterate for all data. There is no getting out of incorrect data, if you feed garbage to the model the model cannot learn.